# Two extra monitors with speakers as stereo output. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors

I recently bought two extra monitors and they both have stereo speakers.
One is on the right of my main monitor and the other one on the left.
They are set up as two different stereo setups (renamed to right/left monitor respectively)

I would like to configure them so they are one stereo output with the right audio channel playing through both channels of the right monitor, 
and the left audio channel playing through both channels of left monitor.

Any help with this would be great, I'm fine with extra software as long as it's free. (I must still be able to switch to my headset).

Comment: How are they connected? Can't you use an audio splitter cable? Optionally, you probably can create your own cable that does this, if they are indeed 3.5mm jack plugs.

Comment: they are connected with(dual sided) 3.5mm jack but if i use a slitter i eider don't have stereo (just dual sound witch can be done in software) or i wont have both speakers on the display. i'm more looking for a decent software solution

Answer (score 3):

I found out a way to do it. You need a virtual audio able (i used [VB-Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm)) and [VoiceMeeter Banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) (both free).

1. make sure the programs mentioned above are installed
2. right click the sound icon in the system tray -> sounds -> playback and set "cable input" as default input device.
3. navigate to recording and right click "VoiceMeeter output" ->properties ->listen, check listen to this device and select "VoiceMeeter input" from the list.
4. do the same for "VoiceMeeteraux output" and respectively "VoiceMeeter aux input"
5. open VoiceMeeter
6. for hardware input 1 select "Cable output" and make sure you deselect "A1" and select both "B1" and "B2". (leave hardware input 1 and 2 empty)
7. under virtual inputs-> "VoiceMeeter VAIO" make sure only "A1" is selected and drag the red ball to the left (middle). ("A1" wil be the left output)
8. under virtual inputs-> "VoiceMeeter AUX" make sure only "A2" is selected and drag the red ball to the right (middle). ("A2" will be the right output)
9. under "master selection" make sure the first 2 (from the left) "mono buttons are selected" (1st one is "A1" and one is "A2")
10. on the top right next to hardware out click "A1" and select the left monitor/speakers.
11. click "A2" and select the right monitor/speakers.
12. keep VoiceMeeter open, after it is closed it wil; work again as soon as it's opened again (if this is your main audio output id advice adding the program to the startup on boot list)

DONE it should look like this (while music is playing):
[click for picture of correct settings for VoiceMeeter Banana.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL3Xr.png)

If you want to use a headphone as well/as primary you can go to "cable output" ->properties -> listen and select your headphones from the list like in step 3.

Now you will hear sound from your headphones. As soon as you launch VoiceMeeter Banana, the sound will go to your monitors/speakers. As soon as you close it, it will go back to the headphones. (This will take a sec or 2/3.)

Comment: Works great!  Thanks.  Did you ever figure out a way to use normal volume controls as well?

Comment: @Goddard no, I set this up for my brother's pc so I haven't played with it much and he since got other speakers so he doesn't use it anymore.